# Content not appearing in wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new theme, and when I add content to my theme, it does not appear. When I switch to a default theme like twenty eleven, the content appears on the page. What php files am I missing?

Comment: Please provide some code, or at least a directory structure of your theme. We can't tell you what files you're missing unless you tell us which ones you have.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview), index.php is the common fallback for every template in that tree.